Django reatApi Request user is Anonymous when using jwt cookies
I'm building a new django restApi app within my users app I'm using jwt authentication currently I'm able to register, login , store cookies and send get request after logging in with a valid credentials.
My issue is when I'm getting an authinticated get request I'm not able to see request's user it shown as AnonymousUser. I'm attachinf my login post request and an endpoint restApi get request code.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed

# Create your views here.
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
import jwt,datetime
class RegisterView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data)

class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
        if user is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found')
        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Incorrect password')
        payload={'id':user.id,'exp':datetime.datetime.utcnow()+datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
                 'iat':datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
        response = Response()
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt',value=token,httponly=True)
        response.data={'jwt':token}
        return response

class UserView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if token is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticatedddd')
        try:
            payload=jwt.decode(token,'secret',algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
        user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class UsserLogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        response = Response()
        response.delete_cookie('jwt')
        response.data = {'message': 'You have been logged out'}
        return response




from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
import jwt

from .models import Subject, Question
from .serializers import SubjectSerializer, YearsSerializer


# Create your views here.
class SubjectsView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')
        if token is None:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
        try:
            jwt.decode(token,'secret',algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
        subjects = Subject.objects.filter()
        serializer = SubjectSerializer(subjects, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)```



I was looking for a way to store a token with it's relevant user with no success


Of course, there is no user being bound to the request after all. You are just authenticating the JWT.
